# First argument -h is not a valid variable

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

I am trying to simpligy my life by defining a function that gets the series expansion of $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-h)$ (at $x=0$) by the following code,

```mathematica
S[h_, n_ : 4] := Series[f[x + h], {h, 0, n}]
```

The intend was to use `S` as `S[h]`=$f(x+h)$ and `S[-h]`=$f(x-h)$. However, I keep encountering "First argument -h is not a valid variable." in the latter invocation. I have tried `Module`, `Block` and `/.` with no resolve. Please help me out!

I'd also like to keep `n` to be SetDelayed because I'd want to have series expansions of different error order.

Comment: I don't think you've accurately provided your code, because I don't see `h` at all on the right hand side of your definition and so I don't understand how it could be causing that error.

Comment: @lericr oops, `h0` is supposed to be `h`. Corrected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`h` is a local to  `Series`, you cannot use it as a functionargument.

Try

```
S[sign_, n_ : 4] := Series[f[x + sign h], {h, 0, n}]

S[+1]
```

$f(x)+h f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$

```
S[-1]
```

$f(x)-h f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)-\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$

Comment: Thanks this helps for my current need! But can you also suggest what I'd need to do to have h as a variable so that I can, say, use it like `S[m]`?

Comment: Try  definition `S[sign_, n_ : 4] = 
 Function[h,  Normal[Series[f[x + sign h], {h, 0, n}]]]` and use it `S[1 ][h]`

Comment: Thanks, that works but demands me to use `Simplify` which is not the case when I use your original solutions. I guess I cannot get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
s[h_, n_ : 4] := Normal[f[t] + O[t, x]^(n + 1)] /. t -> x + h
s[h] + s[-h]
```

[image]

Comment: So, `Normal[]` makes the `Series[...]` get evaluated before the ReplaceAll, `/.`. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @kichapps `Normal` remove the `little O` , `O[y - x]^5`.

Comment: Got it. However, the `Normal` is forcing me to use `Simplify` with `(s[h]-s[-h])/h` and I am not sure why. `Simplify` is also factorizing `h` outside the bracket which is quite annoying.